# Indexerror: no such group python

Tags: python, regex

First of all: I'm feeling really dumb because I know this is a simple question with the answer right under my nose. I have looked answers everywhere but none seems to fit my question.

I am trying to fetch the number of an answer in a page using selenium.
This is what I have:

```
if browser.find_elements_by_css_selector("tr.unreaded"):
print "There's messages unreaded!"
unread_answers = browser.find_elements_by_css_selector("tr.unreaded")
for unread_row in unread_answers:
    row_id = unread_row.get_attribute("id")
    m = re.search('answer_row_\d*', row_id)
    row_number = m.group(1)
    print row_number
```

This is the peace of HTML document I'm currently looking for:

```
<tr id="answer_row_3121238" class="bla bla bla">
...
<tr id="answer_row_3121428" class="bla bla bla">
...
<tr id="answer_row_3124238" class="bla bla bla">
```

I'm getting this error: `IndexError: no such group`.

I know there is resulted beeing fetched because I tried:

```
if browser.find_elements_by_css_selector("tr.unreaded"):
print "There's messages unreaded!"
unread_answers = browser.find_elements_by_css_selector("tr.unreaded")
for unread_row in unread_answers:
    row_id = unread_row.get_attribute("id")
    m = re.search('answer_row_\d*', row_id)
    if m:
        print "Fetched results!"
    row_number = m.group(1)
    print row_number
```

The output was:
`Fetched results!`

`Fetched results!`

`Fetched results!`

If I try to:

```
print m
```

I get three objects beeing the output.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You haven't used any capturing parentheses in your regex, so there are no groups.

```
m = re.search('answer_row_(\d+)', row_id)
```

Also note you should use `+`, for *one or more* digits, not *.

Comment: I have used your solution but something strange happened. Output: `3121238 AtrributeError: 'nonetype' object has no attribute 'group'`. I got the first number I wanted but it didn't fetch the other two.

Comment: Ok. I got this. My code is structured the entire way around. Thank you for your answer. I will fix it.

Answer (score 4):

Because your regex has no groups. Numbered groups are indicated by `(...)`, and named groups are indicated by `(?P<...>...)`. Yours has neither.